# How to create table and set values to table cells using values in the same function

Tags: javascript, html-table

This block of code is to create 3 arrays with the values pulled from the user's input in a popup menu in the HTML file, but the values here are needed to fill in the table below.

```
var arrM = new Array;      var arrT = new Array;         var arrA = new Array; 
arrM[0] = mod0.mod.value;  arrT[0] = mod0.target.value;  arrA[0] = mod0.actual.value; 
arrM[1] = mod1.mod.value;  arrT[1] = mod1.target.value;  arrA[1] = mod1.actual.value; 
arrM[2] = mod2.mod.value;  arrT[2] = mod2.target.value;  arrA[2] = mod2.actual.value; 
arrM[3] = mod3.mod.value;  arrT[3] = mod3.target.value;  arrA[3] = mod3.actual.value; 
arrM[4] = mod4.mod.value;  arrT[4] = mod4.target.value;  arrA[4] = mod4.actual.value; 
arrM[5] = mod5.mod.value;  arrT[5] = mod5.target.value;  arrA[5] = mod5.actual.value; 
arrM[6] = mod6.mod.value;  arrT[6] = mod6.target.value;  arrA[6] = mod6.actual.value; 
arrM[7] = mod7.mod.value;  arrT[7] = mod7.target.value;  arrA[7] = mod7.actual.value; 
arrM[8] = mod8.mod.value;  arrT[8] = mod8.target.value;  arrA[8] = mod8.actual.value; 
arrM[9] = mod9.mod.value;  arrT[9] = mod9.target.value;  arrA[9] = mod9.actual.value;
```

the code in between the block above and the block below(not shown here) is just to compute the average values and does not interact with the block below

the code below is to create a table with the same number of rows as the number of rows the user filled in the popup menu.

```
var tableGenerator = document.getElementById("tableGenerator");
tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.style.width = '500px';
tbl.style.height = '100px';
tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
tbl.style.margin = '50px';
tbl.style.float = 'left';
if (j < 6) {
    j = 6;
}
for (var a = 0; a < j+1; a++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (var b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
        if (a == j && b == 3) {
            break;
        } else {
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
            td.style.border = '1px solid black';
            if (a == 0 && b == 0) {
                var newtext = document.createTextNode(Text);
                var celltext = "Year   " + year.value + "  Semester   " + semester.value;
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(celltext));
                td.setAttribute('colSpan', '3'); break;
            }
//this else block below here obviously doesn't work, but this idea is there and I want something that 
//works like the pseudo code below
              else {
                for (a = 1; a < j; a++) {
                    tbl[a][0] = arrM[a];
                    tbl[a][1] = arrT[a];
                    tbl[a][2] = arrA[a];
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }tableGenerator.appendChild(tbl);
```

I am very unfamiliar with HTML/JS/CSS, is it possible for us to access cell values of a table as if it is an array? or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you'll need to either create text nodes and assign the content of that node, or assign the content to the `textContent`, `innerText` or `innerHTML` properties to give the table cells their values.

```
td.textContent = 'Hello'; // This is the preferred property for text.
```

The help you achieve this it would be wise to structure your data in a way that you can loop over, because you're basically doing the same thing in a specific order. For example:

```
var data = [
  arrM,
  arrT,
  arrA
];
```

This will put your arrays in another array. Now you can loop over the `data` array and create a table row for each array, and a table cell for each item in the nested array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // ... create table row.
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    // ... create table cell and assign textContent property.
  }
}
```

Examine the example below. It's a runnable version of the thing I've explained above. I hope it helps you out.

```js
function createTable(headers, values) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  
  // Build <thead>
  var tableHeader = table.createTHead();
  
  // Create <tr> inside <thead>
  var tableHeaderRow = tableHeader.insertRow();
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    // Create <th>
    var tableHeaderCell = document.createElement('th');
    
    // Set text of <th> to value in array.
    tableHeaderCell.textContent = headers[i];
    
    // Add <th> to <tr> inside <thead>
    tableHeaderRow.appendChild(tableHeaderCell);
  }

  // Build <tbody>
  var tableBody = table.createTBody();
  for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    // Create <tr> inside <tbody>
    var tableBodyRow = tableBody.insertRow();

    for (var k = 0; k < values[j].length; k++) {
      // Create <td> inside <tr>
      var tableBodyCell = tableBodyRow.insertCell();
      
      // Set text of <td> to value in array.
      tableBodyCell.textContent = values[j][k];
    }
  }

  // Add <table> to the <body>
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

var titles = [
  'One',
  'Two',
  'Three'
];

var characters = [
  ['Batman', 'Robin', 'Batgirl'],
  ['Joker', 'Two-Face', 'Poison Ivy'],
  ['James Gordon', 'Alfred Pennyworth', 'Clayface']
];

createTable(titles, characters);
```